# グラフの描画プログラムを別のプログラムで起動する方法

Tags: python, python3

タイトル通りですがうまくいきません。

graph_test.py

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph_test1():   
    plt.title('test')
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")        
    array_x = np.arange(0,5,1)
    array_y = [1,2,3,4,5] 
    plt.plot(array_x,array_y,label="value")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def graph_test2():   
    plt.title('test')
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")        
    array_x = np.arange(0,5,1)
    array_y = [5,4,3,2,1] 
    plt.plot(array_x,array_y,label="value")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph_test1()
graph_test2()
```

start_test.py
これは2つ起動方法を試しましたがどちらもうまくいきませんでした。

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['python','graph_test.py'])
print("")
print(output.decode())

a = subprocess.call("python %s" % 'graph_test.py')  
print(a)
```

実行結果
正しくグラフを出力するにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

```
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)

0
```

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(['python','difficulty_graph.py'])` の `difficulty_graph.py` は `graph_test.py` の間違いではないでしょうか？ こちらの環境は Python3.6.6 ですが、`subprocess.check_output(['python', 'graph_test.py'])` は正常に動作しました。

Comment: プログラムの名前を変えるのを忘れていました。変更しましたが先ほどと同じ出力結果になりました。

Comment: `python graph_test.py`で実行したらグラフは出力されますか？それと`subprocess`を使って起動した場合ではどのような違いがありますか？

Comment: 私はspyder上でプログラムを動かしていますが、graph_test.pyでの実行は上手くいっています。start_testでの呼び出した後の出力がうまくいかないのです。subprocessを使った挙動は上記実行結果の通りです。

Comment: Windows10でspyder上から動かすとstart_testでの呼び出し後の出力がないケースがありました。コマンドプロンプトやpowershellから動かすと正常に動きます。

Answer (score 0):

質問のコードには問題はありません。`Figure(640x480)`という表示は、matplotlibのデフォルトのFigureオブジェクトなので正常な出力であり、正常終了しています。グラフが出力されないのは、環境の問題だと思われます。

PythonからPythonのコードを呼ぶ時は、subprocessを使わずにimportした方がいいと思います。`start_test.py`は、次のようになります。

```
import graph_test

graph_test.graph_test1()
graph_test.graph_test2()
```

`subprocess`を使うと環境依存になります。`subprocess`を使う場合は、公式ドキュメントのsubprocessのページの [Popen コンストラクター](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) の項目にあるプロセスの生成をよく理解してから使ったほうがいいと思われます。例えば、`subprocess.call("python %s" % 'graph_test.py')`は、POSIXではエラーになり、`subprocess.call("python %s" % 'graph_test.py', shell=Tru)`とする必要があります。